# How do specify custom comparator function for a specific column in backgrid.js?

Tags: javascript, backgrid

I have a column in a collection that needs custom sort.
How to assign custom comparator to a column definition, so when the user clicks on the title of the column to see properly sorted values?

Please check my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ntodorov/3zaw3hdr/  this is the code that I need to solve:

```
var columns = [{
  name: "pn",
  label: "Paragraph Number",
  cell: "string",
  //!!! -- this does not work --!!!
  comparator: paragraphNumbersSort
}];
```

Initially, the collection uses the custom comparator to properly sort, but after clicking the column title is uses the build in string sort.
This is code snipped same as the jsfiddle:

```js
var paragraphNumbersSort = function (a, b){
  var a1 = a.split('.');
  var b1 = b.split('.');
  var diff = a1.length - b1.length;
  
  if (diff < 0)
    for(var i = diff; i < 0; i++)
      a1.push("0");
  else
    for(var i = 0; i < diff; i++)
      b1.push("0");
   
  var res = 0;
  a1.some(function(n, i){
    res = n - b1[i];
    return (res != 0 );
  });
  
  return res;
};

var numbers = [{pn: "2.10"}, 
  {pn: "66.9.90008.56.5"}, 
  {pn: "1.1"},
  {pn: "1.2"},
  {pn: "1.12"},
  {pn: "2.10.1"},
  {pn: "2.10.4"},
  {pn: "0"}];

//this will properly sort the collection
var paragraphs = new Backbone.Collection(numbers,
{
  comparator : function (a, b){
    return paragraphNumbersSort(a.get("pn"), b.get("pn"));
  }
});

var columns = [{
    name: "pn",
    label: "Paragraph Number",
    cell: "string",
    //!!! -- this does not work --!!!
    comparator: paragraphNumbersSort
  }];

// Initialize a new Grid instance
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
  columns: columns,
  collection: paragraphs
});

// Render the grid and attach the root to your HTML document
$("#main").append(grid.render().el);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backgrid.js/0.3.8/backgrid.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/underscore/1.5.2/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/1.1.0/backbone.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/wyuenho/backgrid/master/lib/backgrid.js"></script>


<div style="float:left">  
Click on the title "Paragraph Number" to see the problem.
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might want to use `sortValue` instead of `comparator` in your column model

Comment: I saw that, but i could not see how it will work in my case. It returns the value, in my case that no good. If i waned to do transformation of it and pass it to standard comparator yes, but not in custom comparator.

Comment: It might be the only thing you can leverage, since they don't expose the comparison.

Comment: I see. There is a “ugly” workaround to create artificial id colum after sorting the collection and pass that id from the model as sortValue. And i need to monitor if the collection is modified and repeat the process...